# Do I need a working DNS server to resolve another DNS server

Tags: dns, webserver, nameserver

I suspect this question might be more suitable to networking stack exchange but I didnt find any such site, so this seemed like the best place to ask it.

I recently moved back to my native country and though the internet speeds here are tolerable, often the DNS server of the local ISP exchange goes down leaving me without internet for a couple of days or so. I was wondering if I could use the [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) to connect to the internet when the ISP DNS was down , but I was not sure I needed a working DNS server in my local ISP to resolve the Google DNS

Please migrate or close this question if you feel its in the wrong section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ISP DNS is required. Just setup your local DNS to use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. If necessary you can set your router to distribute those addresses and bypass your local ISP altogether.

Comment: When you mean local dns,you mean the one in my laptop right ?

Comment: correct. are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Using Windows 7, I know how to change the dns settings in the adapter but I was not sure if it would suffice

Comment: Sure, that's all you need to do